# Amount textbox in Authorize.NET SIM method

Tags: asp.net, .net, authorize.net

I want to integrate authorize.net SIM into my asp.net website. Is there any way I can have a text box for amount in the payment page. My client wants the user to enter the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to have the page load with the textbox capturing the amount needed for payment. Then you need to create a form with all of the variables required by the SIM API and use JavaScript to submit the form.